# How to deal with 2x2 Y-component sampling factors in a 16x8 JPEG image?

Tags: jpeg

This question concerns building JPEG decoders.

Below is a sample image I generated with [Photopea](https://www.photopea.com/). It is 16x8. The left 8x8 is black, and the right 8x8 is white. It is encoded YCbCr, so three components.

[image]

If the sampling factors for Y=2x1, and Cb/Cr=1x1, it would make sense because I then get two luminance blocks, one for each of left and right, and one Cb and Cr block each for color.

But instead, the file actually has Y sampling factors of 2x2, and Cb/Cr sampling factors of 1x1.

What does it mean to have sampling factors of 2x2 in a 16x8 image? This means I end up with four DCT blocks of 8x8, giving me 16 lines of data, 8 extra lines that are unnecessary.

If I go strictly by the [T-81 spec](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf), section A.1.1 gives formulas that tell me my Cb and Cr blocks will actually have resolutions of 8x4, clearly less than the 8x8 minimum they should have.

What should be proper behavior for a JPEG decoder in this scenario?